# App delegate and View Controller in iOS4

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiviewcontroller, ios4

With multi-tasking in iOS4, the home button puts the app into background and when it comes back into foreground I want the View Controller to 'refresh' (and hence viewWillAppear to be called). I put this in the app delegate thought this should work but nothing happens

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    //  
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 }


 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [viewController.view reloadInputViews];
 }
```

Can anyone help me with forcing a view controller to 'execute'/refresh when it is already showing?

Comment: Please post the code where you instantiate viewController and also post the reloadInputViewsCode. Remember that willEnterForeground is only called if your app was in a suspended state. The cpu may close most suspended apps at any time for memory or other reasons. In that case, applicationDidFinishLaunching will be called.

Comment: Hi Run Loop, note your request and added above. The app reads the pasteboard and update data in the view. The user may go out of the app and copy new data into the pasteboard, when he gets back into the app, it needs to refresh the view. This is executed in viewWillAppear and works fine in iOS3, now applicationWillEnterForeground is called in iOS4. But how do I tell the View Controller to refresh and hence viewWillAppear executes?

Comment: Without seeing the code for reloadInputViews it is difficult, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call viewWillAppear explicitly e.g.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [viewController.view reloadInputViews];

    [viewController viewWillAppear];
 }
```

Comment: That's so cool, I didn't even know you can do that. Tested it and it worked (in the simlulator, have other issues on device, but I don't think it is related). For other readers I was going to use the work around suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187642/ios4-removing-app-from-memory-via-code. But I'm going with Run Loop.