# iPhone, how and where do I show a password view at the start of my app and on resume?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

A friend of mine with the iphone OS4 has pointed out that my app doesn't show a password dialog on returning to my app, after pressing home and returning to my app.

He briefly mentioned willEnterForeground  ???

At the moment I have a text field on my first screen, but if I'm going to need a password alert view I may as well use an alert view on the first screen too.

So my question is how do I show my alert if the user resumes to my first screen, the resume event will fire and my first screen will show the alert, that twice.

I need to reliably show the alert once, in this scenario and in resumes to other screens, how do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applicationWillEnterForeground is only called upon resume from suspend. It is not, however, called when an application starts up for the first time. So you will need to handle both scenarios.

This question has a good example: [App delegate and View Controller in iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376695/app-delegate-and-view-controller-in-ios4)

You just need to handle both notifications and display your password view in each of them. I don't think there is any kind of "all in one resume/application is starting" notification.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I must have missed it, where do I call my password view at startup so it doesn't get called upon resume on that view too ?

Comment: If you don't want to have it shown on resume, you should just put it in applicationDidFinishLaunching (both methods should be in your AppDelegate).